# Put saved data in flash of STM32 at the end of all other sections

Tags: stm32, flash, eeprom

I want to emulate EEPROM over flash of STM32F103. Is there a way to use all free flash instead of the only page? How can I initialize starting point of my EEPROM emulation so that it would be after all sections? I tried to add section after .text like

```
.text: ...

.myvars :
{
. = ALIGN(1024);
KEEP(*(.myvars));
KEEP(*(.myvars*));
} > rom
```

and define variable as

```
__attribute__((section(".myvars"))) static const flash_storage Flash_Storage = {
    .magick = "1234567890absdef0987654321",
    .all_stored = USERCONF_INITIALIZER
};
```

but it doesn't helps me: I see some more data after this structure in binary dump.

*UPD*: the solution of this problem quite simple. The section `.myvars` should be after last section in ram, i.e. **after** `.data`!

Comment: Here's a link to ST's [EEPROM emulation](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/ee/ef/d7/87/cb/b7/48/52/CD00165693.pdf/files/CD00165693.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00165693.pdf), in case you haven't seen it. There may be insights in their source code.

Comment: @bitsmack, sounds funny, but I can't find sources of ST's EEPROM emulation. In the RM there's nothing about memory structure.

Comment: Their website is strange, indeed :). [Here's](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-stm32010.html) the software pack for STM32F103/105 microcontrollers.

Comment: @bitsmack, all OK! I just add section .myvars *after* section .data and now all fine! Also I have an error: STM32F103 page size is 1024 bytes, not 2048.

Comment: Great! Glad to know it worked :)  Instead of updating your question, you should add your own answer! This will allow the database to work correctly, and we can also give you upvotes. :)

Comment: But you want it to go into .rom -- are you sure that's where it's going?

Comment: @TimWescott, yes, it works just as I want. Gcc put given section after all data in flash (including constant initializers).

Comment: FYI [two different approaches here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/446893/which-flash-sector-to-write-into/446919#446919) (the third one doesn't apply to STM32F1)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution of such problem is to put the section `.myvars` after latest section in `ram`. In my case it should be after section `.data`. The full linker file:

```
MEMORY
{
    rom (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 128K
    ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 20K
}

ENTRY(reset_handler)

SECTIONS {
  .vector_table 0x08000000 :
  {
    _sisrvectors = .;
    KEEP(*(.vector_table))
    /* ASSERT(. == _isrvectors_tend, "The vector table needs to be 84 elements long!"); */
    _eisrvectors = .;
  } >rom

  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _stext = .;
    *(.text*)
    *(.rodata*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;
  } >rom

  .ARM.extab :
  {
    *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
  } >rom

  .ARM : {
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
  } >rom

  .data :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;
    *(.data*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;
  } >ram AT >rom

  .myvars :
  {
    . = ALIGN(1024);
    KEEP(*(.myvars))
  } > rom

  _ldata = LOADADDR(.data);

  .bss :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sbss = .;
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;
  } >ram
}

PROVIDE(_stack = ORIGIN(ram) + LENGTH(ram));
```

Here is the [code](https://github.com/eddyem/stm32samples/blob/master/F1-nolib/chronometer/flash.c).